# How can I join two tables?

Tags: 7, database

I have a database table whose schema is the following one.

```php
$schema['location'] = array(
  'descritiption' => 'location',
  'fields' => array(
    'locationID' =>  array(
      'description' => 'primary key for patients table',
      'type' => 'serial',
      'unsigned' => TRUE,
      'not null' => TRUE),
    ),
    'addressone' => array (
      'description'    => 'this shows the first line of the address',
      'type'         => 'TEXT'
    ),
    'county' => array(
      'description' => 'this is a county list'
    ),
    'postcode' => array(
      'description' => 'stores the postcode'  
    ),
    'primary_key' => array('locationID')
  )
);
```

How would I join this table with the user table?

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want to query data from both tables by using the join syntax or are you actually trying to combine the two tables together into one?

Comment: Does that table definition even make sense? Have you read the DBTNG documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JOIN`s are a query-level concept and don't really make a lot sense in the context of a schema definition.

I suspect what you're asking is how to add a foreign key from your `location` table to the `users` table. If so I'm afraid you're out of luck; Drupal does not enforce foreign key relationships, so you'll need to define and maintain your relationships at a code level.

There is a `foreign keys` property that can be applied to tables defined by the schema API, but it is [for documentation purposes only](http://drupal.org/node/224333#foreign-keys-added), no foreign keys are ever added at the database level.

Just in case you are asking how to join a table in a query:

```
$query = db_select('location', 'l')
  ->fields('l');

$query->join('users', 'u', 'u.uid = l.uid_column_name');

$results = $query->execute();
```